# Is it possible to change first object's place in array modifier with script?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

In blender i have a curve and a cylinder that i want to go along the curve, and i use array and curve modifiers for that. But i want to change the place where my first cylinder is placed, it is placed in the beginning of the curve, which i don't want. I want to change its position, so that initially it is placed on the curve but not in the beginning of it,i want to give a distance that the cylinders start to be placed from that place.
More specifically i want the cylinders to be placed starting from the point which has distance equal to one cylinder's radius from the curve'a beginning. And that i want to do with python script.
Thank you in advance.